# Any way to open screensaver selection dialog programmatically?

Tags: windows, winapi, screensaver

Any way to open screensaver selection dialog programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `control.exe` with the arguments `desk.cpl,,@screensaver`

Like that:

```
control.exe desk.cpl,,@screensaver
```